# MSMQ and SSIS-Read messages and write them to a table using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, msmq

Basically I want to read messages from MSMQ public queue and push them to a SQL Server table.

Ideally I imagine an SSIS package (that a SQL Server Agent Job can execute every couple of hours) that read the messages and populate a SQL Server table.

I came across SSIS package "Message Queue Task" > Receive but don't know how to read such object and then push it further to a SQL Server table.

I tried Microsoft SQL Server receive function given in documentation but didn't understand.

Comment: You can write an SSIS package or a .NET program to do this.  But your question is currently too broad for SO.

Comment: Thanks for reply,Actually I want this in c++ ,,will give any link where I can see c++ solution

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms701293(v=vs.85) and  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/cpp-code-example-app-connect-access-sql-db?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks sir,I refered these links ,very useful but ,,sir can u send link of inserting data into sql table in odbc c++

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-queries/using-statement-parameters?view=sql-server-ver16